# Task of Stream with HttpClient

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, async-await, dotnet-httpclient

I have this method that returns a Task:

```
public async Task<Stream> GetPDF(string docPath) {
    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(docPath))
        return null;

    docPath = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(docPath.Replace('~', '%'));

    if (docPath.Contains(".."))
        return null;

    var url = ServiceUrl + "api/Document/PDF?docPath=" + docPath;

    using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url))
    using (Stream mystream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync()) {
        return mystream;
    }
}
```

I call it like this:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Render(int documentID) {
    // code to get path from documentID is omitted
    Task<Stream> dataStream = GetPDF(document.DocumentPath);
    return File(dataStream, "application/pdf");
}
```

However, this does not compile because you cannot convert from task to byte. How do I extract the mystream?

Comment: This probably this could help you:

`Task<Stream> dataStream = await GetPDF(document.DocumentPath)`

Comment: @ArturLavrov awaiting it will return a `Stream`, not a `Task<Stream>`.

Answer (score 0):

First the stream will be disposed when the method goes out of scope. Don't dispose of the stream.

```
public async Task<Stream> GetPDF(string docPath) {
    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(docPath))
        return null;

    docPath = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(docPath.Replace('~', '%'));

    if (docPath.Contains(".."))
        return null;

    var url = ServiceUrl + "api/Document/PDF?docPath=" + docPath;

    using (var response = await client.GetAsync(url)) {
        return await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();            
    }
}
```

Next when calling the method you can await it

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Render(int documentID) {
    //...code to get path from documentID is omitted
    Stream dataStream = await GetPDF(document.DocumentPath);
    return File(dataStream, "application/pdf");
}
```